# Is identity permutation cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

One of the theorem that I have a trouble with is

If σ is a cycle of length n, then σ^r is also a cycle if and only if n and r are relatively prime

If σ=(123), then σσσ becomes identity permutation.

As far as I know identity permutation is a cycle. But, if it were true, then above theorem

does not hold since gcd(3.3)=3

Answer (score 3):

A cyclic permutation must have exactly one cycle of length GREATER than $1$.  All the cycles in the identity have length 1. So the identity is not cyclic.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Definition

Comment: Well, I think you'd agree that $(1, 3) = (1, 3)(2)$ is a single cycle (2-cycle), even though it's a product of a 2-cycle and a 1-cycle...

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a cyclic permutation must have exactly one cycle of length $>1$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Definition

Comment: Looks good, thanks for the edit! By the way, the theorem can be strengthened: not only is $\sigma^r$ a cycle if $(n,r)=1$, but in fact it is an $n$-cycle.