# Assessing the proof that the identity permutation $\epsilon$ has an even parity

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, proof-explanation, permutation-cycles

I have seen the proof for why the identity permutation $\epsilon$ is even...but from a superficial level, I find the methods used in the proof to be sort of contradictory. Consider the following 3 claims, which I believe are all true:

1. Permutations can be defined as *even* or *odd* on the basis of the number of transpositions required to *build them*.
2. A transposition is a type of cycle.
3. The identity permutation $\epsilon$ is not a cycle.

Using these three points, it strikes me as contradictory to associate a parity with the identity permutation $\epsilon$.

The claims that trip me up are the combination of 2. and 3. Specifically, if we define a transposition as a type of cycle, but then declare that $\epsilon$ is *not* a cycle, then I would think that it is illogical to construct $\epsilon$ using the composition of some arbitrary number of transpositions given that we know $\epsilon$, itself, is not a cycle.

Stated differently, *I would think that *because the identity permutation is not a cycle* that it would be illogical to construct it from cycles.*

The only thing I can think of that is sort of analogous to this idea is the following:

The number $1$ is not negative, but I can construct it from negative numbers (e.g. $-1 * -1$)

Could someone please help restate these three claims (or, perhaps, redirect my logic-assessment) so that this contradiction disappear?

Comment: Any permutation (including non-cyclic permutations) can be written as a composition of transpositions.

Comment: Starting with the identity, how many transpositions do you need to perform to reach the identity? Zero. Zero is even, so the identity is an even permutation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde from what I have read, I do not believe that is correct...unless I misunderstood the definition of a cycle.

Comment: Often $S_3$ is written down as $\{(1),(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$. What definition of cycle do you have? (not that it matters for this question).

Comment: The point is that your second and third claims are irrelevant. Whether the identity is a cycle or not, it does not matter. Whether a transposition is a cycle or not, it does not matter. All that matters is that the identity can be built up from 0 transpositions, and 0 is even.

Comment: @DietrichBurde "a cycle must contain 2 or more elements"

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151548/is-identity-permutation-cyclic

Comment: No, that's the definition of a *cyclic permutation*, see Wikipedia link of your link. I mean "cycle".

Comment: It is worth pointing out that permutations can have many different representations.  While we could and often do restrict ourselves to talking about the disjoint cyclic representation of a permutation (*in which case the identity permutation in $S_3$ might be written as $(1)(2)(3)$ as the product of the three trivial cycles each of length 1*), here it is worth pointing out that we can also express the identity permutation as a product of transpositions... either as the empty product, or as $(12)(12)$, or as $(12)(12)(13)(13)$ or any number of other representations, all of which have an even #

Answer (score 1):

The map $\epsilon : S_n \rightarrow \:${$\pm1$} is a homomorphism. Say $\sigma \in S_n$, so $\epsilon(1 \: \sigma) = \epsilon(1) \epsilon(\sigma) = \epsilon(\sigma)$ implies identity permutation must have even parity = 1.

As for whether identity is a transposition or not doesn't matter anymore because for the homomorphism above to work, it must have even parity.